# Did not find named query

Tags: spring, hibernate, repository, entity, spring-data-jpa

I have this entity :

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private Date birthdate;
private int phonenumber;
private int cin;
private String address;
private String password;
private String email;
//Getters & Setters ..
}
```

And this DAO class :

```
@Repository
public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

List<User> findAllUsersByFirstnameOrderByFirstnameDesc(String firstName);
List<User> findAllUsersByLastnameOrderByLastnameDesc(String Lastname);
List<User> findAllUsersByFirstnameAndLastnameOrderByFirstname(String firstAndLastname);
List<User> findAllUsersByFirstnameOrLastnameContaining(String nameContent);
List<User> findAllUsersByPhonenumber(int phoneNumber);
List<User> findAllUsersByEmailContaining(String email);
User findUserByCin(int cin);
}
```

And when I run it I get this error :

> **Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
>       at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)**
>
> **DEBUG org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery - Did not find named query User.findAllUsersByEmailContaining**
>
> **DEBUG org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery - Did not find named query
>   User.findAllUsersByFirstnameOrLastnameContaining**

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong but I'm not getting how this query works, List<User> findAllUsersByFirstnameAndLastnameOrderByFirstname(String firstAndLastname); --- when it needs 2 params and you are passing a single param.

Comment: Well that's the problem, it's not working and I don't know why. Can you elaborate on that. @Arun

Comment: For the query that I have in the comment you need to pass 2 params for the method like findAllUsersByFirstn‌​ameAndLastnameOrderBy‌​Firstname(String firstName, String LastName);

Comment: I don't know how I didn't see that........... THANKS

Comment: Also findAllUsersByEmailContaining(String email); this should work if it doesn't try @Query and write the query yourself. See 5.3.4 section in http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: Also I think the same goes for this, it needs 2 params ---- List<User> findAllUsersByFirstnameOrLastnameContaining(String nameContent);

Comment: emm yeah I think so too, but for the email query it'snt working..can you tell me why cause I don't see any problem with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120996/discussion-between-arun-and-moatez-bouhdid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Arun I was able to resolve my problems stated below :

change this :

```
List<User> findAllUsersByFirstnameAndLastnameOrderByFirstname(String firstAndLastname);
```

To :

```
List<User> findAllUsersByFirstnameAndLastnameOrderByFirstname(String firstname, String lastname);
```

**And** 
This :

```
List<User> findAllUsersByFirstnameOrLastnameContaining(String nameContent);
```

To

```
List<User> findAllUsersByFirstnameOrLastnameLike(String nameContent);
```

**And** This

```
List<User> findAllUsersByFirstnameOrLastnameContaining(String nameContent);
```

To

```
List<User> findAllUsersByFirstnameOrLastnameContaining(String firstname, String lastname);
```

For further information you can check this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).